# What does "in turn of the centrury country" mean?

Tags: meaning

I have come across it in this [video](https://youtu.be/oIPoKz7vfsY). It is right at 3 minutes. Here it goes:

> **In turn of the century India and Africa**, man eating animals were basically par for the course.

Comment: Dictionary.com: [turn of the century](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/turn-of-the-century)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Turn of the century" means either "about 1900" or "about 2000" (or occasionally 1800, 1700 etc).

From the context I'd guess that it means "about 1900" in this sentence.

So it means that man-eating animals were common in India and Africa in the time 1890-1910 (roughly).

The wider context for this is that much of Africa and India was under British imperial rule at the time.

Answer (score 1):

The compound modifier *turn-of-the-century* means "of or related to the period near the turn of the century."

So depending on context, "turn-of-the-century India" might mean something like, "India as it was during the period roughly between 1890 and 1905."